# Correct way to add Generic types inheritance

Tags: swift

I have created these classes:

```
class BaseViewModel<NavigatorType> {
    typealias Navigator = NavigatorType

    var navigator: Navigator!
}

class BaseViewController<ViewModel: BaseViewModel<Any>>: UIViewController {
    typealias ViewModel = ViewModel

    var viewModel: ViewModel!
}

class MyVC: BaseViewController<MyViewModel> {

}

class MyViewModel: BaseViewModel<MyNavigator> {

}
```

Now the problem is I receive this error on `MyVC` class:

> 'BaseViewController' requires that 'MyViewModel' inherit from
>   'BaseViewModel`<Any>`'

If I remove `BaseViewModel<Any>` from my `BaseViewController` generic parameter then the error goes. But I want to restrict view controller's generic ViewModel to inherit from BaseViewModel only.

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The specialized type `BaseViewModel<MyNavigator>` is different from the specialized type `BaseViewModel<Any>`. I suspect you're picturing it like `BaseViewModel<MyNavigator>` can override/inherit from `BaseViewModel<Any>` since `MyNavigator` is a more specific `Any`. But Swift doesn't work that way. I don't know enough about the internals of Swift to know *why* it doesn't, but it doesn't!

Perhaps try making BaseViewModel a protocol instead:

```
protocol BaseViewModel {
    associatedtype Navigator

    var navigator: Navigator! { get }
}

class BaseViewController<ViewModel: BaseViewModel>: UIViewController {
    var viewModel: ViewModel!
}

class MyVC: BaseViewController<MyViewModel> {
    func foo() {
        viewModel.navigator.bar()
        print(viewModel.mySpecificProperty)
    }
}

class MyViewModel: BaseViewModel {
    var navigator: MyNavigator!
    var mySpecificProperty: String = "Hello!"
}

class MyNavigator {
    func bar() {
        print("MyNavigator bar")
    }
}
```

If the goal is to give view controllers a specific typed view model to play with, that should do it.